# Checkbox not working as intended in Mixed reality toolkit V2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

Checkboxes are currently unusable in the new toolkit, as you cannot bind functions to states.

There is a development commit on GitHub, but it's not usable yet, so I need a script to work around, without changing the toolkit.

Should be able to easily set starting state, and call functions on state change - which you currently can't.

Comment: Andras, thanks for your contribution here! Would you mind rewording it into a question and answer? It's perfectly acceptable on Stack Overflow to answer your own question immediately after asking it. At the moment you've effectively proposed a solution (albeit a workaround) within your question!

Comment: I think I can't do that yet, because I don't have enough reputation (15) to create a question and answer, or is there an other way to do that?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can answer a question even with a reputation of 1. So firstly edit the question to be an actual question, then once you're done fill in the "Your Answer" section. Just in case, I'll upvote your question once you've edited it to give you some rep! (BTW - once we're done with all this, we should try and delete these comments as they're not pertinent to the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that works without changing the toolkit, and should work on newer versions.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Interactable))]
public class CheckBoxInteractableSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool startChecked = true;

    public UnityEvent OnCheck;
    public UnityEvent OnUncheck;

    private Interactable interactable;
    private int state = 1;

    void Start()
    {
        interactable = GetComponent<Interactable>();

        if (OnCheck == null)
            OnCheck = new UnityEvent();
        if (OnUncheck == null)
            OnUncheck = new UnityEvent();

        OnCheck.AddListener(Checked);
        OnUncheck.AddListener(UnChecked);

        //works with 2 dimensions only
        if (startChecked)
        {
            if (interactable.GetDimensionIndex() == 0) interactable.IncreaseDimension();
        }
        else
        {
            if (interactable.GetDimensionIndex() == 1) interactable.IncreaseDimension();
        }

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (interactable == null) return;

        //state check
        if (state != interactable.GetDimensionIndex())
        {
            state = interactable.GetDimensionIndex();
            if (state == 0) OnUncheck.Invoke();
            if(state == 1) OnCheck.Invoke();
        }
    }

    private void Checked()
    {

    }

    private void UnChecked()
    {

    }
}
```

Works with checkboxes only (2 dimension), you can set the default state for the checkbox, and you can subscribe to states on state changes.